# Syntax error in For loop of batch script

Tags: batch-file

I don't understand why this keeps returning syntax errors. Can somebody take look and tell me how I can get it to correctly work.

for /L %%n in (1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000) do
(
    test.exe %%n
)

Comment: If you understand why you ask?

Comment: I meant I didn't understand, sorry. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

FOR /L syntax is `for /L %%x in (start,step,end) do` which sets `%%x` to start for the first loop, alters it by step for each loop until it reaches `end`.

remove the `/L` if you want to run `test.exe` with the contents of a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate a list of values, then you want a simple FOR with no option:

```
@echo off
for %%N in (1 10 100 1000 10000 100000) do echo %%N
```

result

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
```

If you want to iterate a range of numbers, then use the /L option. The IN clause requires three arguments - startValue, Increment, and endValue

```
@echo off
for /l %%N in (0 10 100) do echo %%N
```

result

```
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

Your code with the /L option and 6 values in the IN() clause is invalid

Comment: Okay thanks. But Why do I have to write the whole statement on one line? For examle, @echo off
for /l %%N in (0 10 100) do echo %%N
How can I place a do this using muliple lines.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your followup question, just add parentheses to add more commands in a loop.

```
@echo off
for /l %%N in (0 10 100) do (
   echo ======[A]======
   echo %%N
   echo ======[B]====== 
)
```